# Xamarin iOS app not able to upload to app store

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, xamarin.ios

I am trying to upload my iOS app to App Store and receiving this error message in an email.

> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
> selectors in MyApp.iOS: accessibilityBrailleMapRenderRegion,
> accessibilityBrailleMapRenderer, activePlayer,
> beginAuthorizationWithRequest:, cancelAuthorizationWithRequest:,
> checkFocusGroupTreeForEnvironment:, commissioningComplete:,
> connectionTypesMask,
> determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler:,
> errorForCHIPErrorCode:, errorToCHIPErrorCode:,
> lookupAdConversionDetails:,
> pairDevice:address:port:discriminator:setupPINCode:error:, playerId,
> serviceExtensionWillTerminate, session:didReceiveData:fromPlayer:,
> session:didReceiveMessage:withData:fromPlayer:,
> session:player:didChangeConnectionState:, session:player:didSaveData:,
> setAccessibilityBrailleMapRenderRegion:,
> setAccessibilityBrailleMapRenderer:, setConnectionTypesMask:,
> setListenPort:, sharedController, sleep:, test:, toggle:. If method
> names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above,
> altering your method names will help prevent this app from being
> flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of
> the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included
> with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information,
> visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

To resolve this, I searched all method names in the solution.

The only match I found is `didReceiveMessage` in AppDelegate.cs in the iOS project.
`FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);`

full function is here.

```
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
            // this callback will not be fired 'till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

            // If you disable method swizzling, you'll need to call this method. 
            // This lets FCM track message delivery and analytics, which is performed
            // automatically with method swizzling enabled.
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Do your magic to handle the notification data
            System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
        }
```

I have no idea how I can resolve this issue.

One solution was to change the `Linker Behavior:` settings to `Link All` But then App Code is breaking.

Has someone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a reproducible problem which limits the capabilities for you to receive the proper answer, so this answer is only to my best knowledge.

As far as I am aware, this can happen only if some package that you use call those methods. As such the solution is to remove that package and recreate your project without it.